# Price filter with fixed price in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to filter products with price. But getting some issue with my requirement. Like in default magento price filter is working with range. When we need with fixed price filter.

```
1. $0.00 - $10.00
2. $100.00 - $200.00
3. $300.00 - $400.00
```

Above is how it comes in default magento. When i click on 2nd filter i can see url like `?price=2-10` and it is filtering products between $10 to $20.

Now in our case we have only three fixed product price in store. So we dont need range filter but instead should be with fixed price filter.

```
1. $10
2. $25
3. $45
```

and when i click on 2nd filter, url should be like `?price=25`

Thanks,

Comment: for that you have to give range 0-25 then it will work otherwise you have to rewrite the `layer/filter/price` model to do your logic.

Comment: If i will give range 0-25 it will filter from $0 to $25. But i dont want range anymore.

Comment: what you want to achieve here only product that have price `25`?

Comment: Yes only products with price $25

Answer (score 0):

@Hardik If you can have filter like ?price=25-25 instead of ?price=25 then it will filter products having price 25.

Comment: Thanks Nalin, but i have already tried. And it if i am using ?price=25-25 it is filtering with price between 600,00 - 625,00

Comment: @Hardik It's working for me, are you using any extension for it?

Comment: Yes i am using EcommerceTeam SLN using. But already tried in default fresh magento.

Comment: So, you need to check whether this module overrides Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price or not? If yes, then please look into methods getMaxPriceInt and getPriceRange logic

Answer (score 0):

simply rewrite the model `Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`

in this `apply` function add this code

```
    public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
{

    $filter = $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar());
    if (!$filter) {
        return $this;
    }
     $select =  $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
                 $select->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('eq' => $filter));
  $state = $this->_createItem(
        $stateLabel, $filter
    )->setVar($this->_requestVar);
    /* @var $state Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item */

    $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($state);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is working. But issue is. I can not see custom price filter is selected on left column.

Comment: Also when i am trying with multiple filter, it is only working with the 1st one.

Comment: then you have more customize on that because default magento selected filter in `state`

Comment: Do you have idea how i can add custom price filter list, that will work with above code?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/comment-page-1/ at the end add this code in apply function

Comment: I have tried but not getting it exactly.

Comment: what are you not getting?

Comment: In _getItemsData function i have added my three custom price filter. but i am not getting any links on it or not .

Comment: you mean you don't get the link on them?

Comment: Yes. not getting link on it. only getting titles.

Comment: check where you missed something did you set custom param `$this->_requestVar = 'sale';`